# SQL Query with drop or null on statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server

On a Userpage we show Awardpictures recived from 2 sql tables.

In zg15_auszeichnungen_vergeben which contains all user awards in form from award type id`s, award dates ... we read over the users pilotID the award datas.

Over a LEFT JOIN from zg15_auszeichnungen_main we get the Awardpicture and the Award Name which shows on the page.

```
SELECT v.pilotID, v.auszBereichID, v.auszTypID, v.gameID, v.auszDatum, m.mainGrafik, m.mainName 
FROM zg15_auszeichnungen_vergeben
    LEFT JOIN zg15_auszeichnungen_main m ON v.auszMainID = m.mainID
WHERE v.pilotID = '$pilotID'
            AND v.auszBereichID = 6
            AND v.auszTypID = 100
            AND v.gameID = 1
ORDER BY v.auszDatum;
```

Because there are to many year awards(1 year,2years,3years...12 years) together wit some other awards, i want just show the oldest award of the years (just 12 years instead of all). The year awards have the value 11 from m.mainKatID and the oldest has the highest value from m.mainPunkte.
Other awards like (most Postpoints) have other values (10) in mainKatID.

I'm not familiar with mysql and don't get the result i want.

Comment: Show us some sample data and tell us what would be your expected output

Comment: m.mainGrafik its the Name of the picture.  In the sql where statement i creat an image like  $mainGrafik = "<img src=\"'.$mainGrafik.\">";  So the output now islike :  <img src="mostPoints.png"> <img src="mostFails.png"> <img src="1year.png"> <img src="2years.png"> ... It should be: <img src="mostPoints.png"> <img src="mostFails.png"> <img src="11years.png">

Comment: Please add the table contents to the question. it's really hard to understand what you're doing from this description.

Comment: sorry for my bad english ! i try to add the tables but stuck on the format here, it looks just awefull. i try to explain it better !

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY m.mainKatID DESC LIMIT 3` and set limit to return 3 records.

```
     SELECT 
       v.pilotID, v.auszBereichID, v.auszTypID, v.gameID, v.auszDatum, 
     m.mainGrafik, m.mainName FROM zg15_auszeichnungen_vergeben v
        LEFT JOIN zg15_auszeichnungen_main m ON v.auszMainID = m.mainID
        WHERE v.pilotID = '$pilotID'
        AND v.auszBereichID = 6
        AND v.auszTypID = 100
        AND v.gameID = 1
        ORDER BY m.mainKatID DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: That didnt work. You limit the years output but also the other awards.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery that gets the oldest year award for each `mainID`. Combine that with the non-year awards using `UNION`.

```
SELECT v.pilotID, v.auszBereichID, v.auszTypID, v.gameID, v.auszDatum, m.mainGrafik, m.mainName 
FROM zg15_auszeichnungen_vergeben AS v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM zg15_auszeichnungen_main
    WHERE mainKatID != 11
    UNION
    SELECT m1.*
    FROM zg15_auszeichnungen_main AS m1
    JOIN (SELECT mainID, MAX(mainPunkte) AS maxPunkte
          FROM zg15_auszeichnungen_main
          WHERE mainKatID = 11
          GROUP BY mainID) AS m2
    ON m1.mainID = m2.mainID AND m1.mainPunkte = m2.maxPunkte
    WHERE m1.mainKatID = 11) AS m
ON v.auszMainID = m.mainID
WHERE v.pilotID = '$pilotID'
            AND v.auszBereichID = 6
            AND v.auszTypID = 100
            AND v.gameID = 1
ORDER BY v.auszDatum;
```

Comment: if i add a v to "FROM zg15_auszeichnungen_vergeben v" it works !
Thank your very much.

Comment: I just copied that part from the query in the question, it was missing there.